# Single software or tool chain for written web content with custom HTML and server side code intertwined?

Tags: web-development, html, word-processor

I am looking for a good solution either with a single piece of software or a workflow using multiple tools for managing and editing written content for the web that also has HTML / CSS / JS and server side code intertwined throughout. Nothing too complicated, just basically written content like articles , reviews, tutorials, etc that also has things like tables, graphs, visualizations, images, advanced formatting, etc throughout the written article. The problem I am having is using Visual Studio works perfectly fine for making sure all my markup and programming is working on the page but it makes proofreading difficult as things like grammar and flow cannot be easily checked. Using a Word Processor makes checking grammar and proofreading easy but then you are maintaining two separate files for a given article and have to manually merge any updates to the written content to your actual source code.

It also seems to me like a lot of websites get around this by basically having a box in their web template where the written text content simply gets injected from a CMS. This ends up with very harsh segmented web design, I am trying to create a very natural flow where HTML is naturally integrated with the written content.

Also just to note I am new to modern web development, there might be something incredibly obvious I have not been exposed to.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe what you are looking for might be an "open-source static site generator".

I like [Hugo](https://gohugo.io/) but there are many others. ([Top 10 in 2020](https://scotch.io/tutorials/top-10-static-site-generators-in-2020), blogpost, one of the first  search results )

The integration of  RStudio, Hugo, Github and Netlify is quite something. [Workflow Details here](https://bookdown.org/yihui/blogdown/workflow.html)

Write markdown in  RStudio , Hugo picks it up. When you are done publish it to github, it make a connection to your hosting company (e.g.Netlify), github publishes to the internet.

Of course you can use other software components and service providers.

If you are a sole blogger or programmer, this might work for you. If you have to deal with many users and editors, and must support both: password-protected webpages *and* a backend (admin area), then go with a classic content  management system, CMS.